# Pegar IMEI via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

É possível através de uma página web conseguir pegar o IMEI do celular de quem acessa utilizando javascript ou qualquer outra coisa?

Comment: Duvido muito, seria uma falha de segurança gravissima permitir isso.

Comment: Não é possível! Como disse o nosso amigo @Articuno seria uma falha de segurança gravíssima! Talvez você consiga essa informação, mas criando uma APP nativo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, não é possível. E isso é bom, por vários motivos, mas principalmente:

- É possível bloquear um aparelho celular remotamente apenas com seu IMEI. Isso é feito geralmente em caso de furto ou roubo. Agora imagine uma pessoal mal-intencionada que tenha colhido seu email através de um site - essa pessoa poderia entrar em contato e tentar extorquir dinheiro de você sob a ameaça de bloquear seu aparelho caso você não pague.
- Javascript nos navegadores não tem acesso a nada que possa identificar uma máquina de forma única. Você não tem como obter o nome do computador na rede, ou acessar a estrutura de diretórios do cliente, por exemplo. A razão segue uma linha parecida com a do motivo anterior: qualquer coisa que você pudesse fazer com essas informações seria uma violação de privacidade.

Se você quer alguma informação do cliente, crie uma página na qual ele possa informar essas coisas manualmente.